# Varnish-Agent installation breaks while make

Tags: ubuntu, make, varnish

I have install varnish in ubuntu 14.04 using [this](https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/ubuntu).

Varnish Version:
`varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-4.0.3 revision b8c4a34)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Varnish Software AS`

Now I m trying to install varnish-agent from the [source](https://github.com/varnish/vagent2) following the *INSTALL.rst* file given. I have installed all the dependencies which are to be met but still my installation breaks at **make**. I searched a lot but not able to figure out why it breaks. Below are the last few lines from **make**

`modules/vstat.c:76:25: error: ‘const struct VSC_desc’ has no member named ‘ctype’
  assert(!strcmp(pt->desc->ctype, "uint64_t"));
                         ^
../include/common.h:125:6: note: in definition of macro ‘assert’
    ((expr) ? (void)(0) : assert_fail(#expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__));
      ^
modules/vstat.c:76:25: error: ‘const struct VSC_desc’ has no member named ‘ctype’
  assert(!strcmp(pt->desc->ctype, "uint64_t"));
                         ^
../include/common.h:125:6: note: in definition of macro ‘assert’
    ((expr) ? (void)(0) : assert_fail(#expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__));
      ^
modules/vstat.c:76:25: error: ‘const struct VSC_desc’ has no member named ‘ctype’
  assert(!strcmp(pt->desc->ctype, "uint64_t"));
                         ^
../include/common.h:125:6: note: in definition of macro ‘assert’
    ((expr) ? (void)(0) : assert_fail(#expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__));
      ^
modules/vstat.c:94:52: error: ‘const struct VSC_desc’ has no member named ‘semantics’
  VSB_printf(out_vsb, "\"flag\": \"%c\", ", pt->desc->semantics);
                                                    ^
make[2]: *** [modules/varnish_agent-vstat.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory /home/ubuntu/vagent2/src
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/ubuntu/vagent2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Please can any one figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error. It was solved downloading the code from master branch.

https://github.com/varnish/vagent2/archive/master.zip